# R console not starting//Import data via 'Put R Var'

Tags: r, console

when I go to Excel, Addins, RExcel and then click on 'Start R' the R console is not starting automatically. Wouldn't be much of a problem but when I start it manually (Windows start menu, R) and try to import Data from Excel into R by using 'Put R Var' it doesn't work - R simply doesn't recognize the name I gave the dataframe.

I am using R Version 2.15.1, Excel 2010 on Windows XP.

Any suggestions how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably R is installed, but Excel cannot find it. I would try to add the path to the R executable to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I did as you suggested but the problem persists. (out of curiosity (if it's not too complicated to explain: how would Excel know that it has to access this environment variable?)

I noticed that RExcel and R are two completely separate folders,i.e. I got one folder C:\Programs\R and another folder called C:\Programs\RExcel - is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Checking the folders in `PATH` is a common means of tracking down executables one needs if the exact location of installation is not known. RExcel probably uses either `PATH`, or the Windows Registry to find R. In regard to your second question, any piece of software can happily live in its own folder, as long as they can find each other.

Answer (score 0):

set the path command and in RExcel menu Set R Server to Foreground and check the checkbox Rguivisible. close excel and restart excel and then start R. This should work.